# resampling errors

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system

I have to reproject my images, but it contains some resampling errors. Any one has any idea on significance of resampling error. Are they neglectable? Is there any good documentation to refer to? I'll do it by GDAL. In my case source coordinate system is WGS84 Lat,Lon (ESPG=4326) and target is MODIS Sinusoidal.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "contains some resampling errors"?  Are you seeking general background on resampling error or help diagnosing a specific anomaly you are seeing in a gdalwarp invocation?

Comment: I just want to know how important this resampling error could be. I'm not RS expert, but now I have to build a raster database. I want to if I should reproject all my data to a certain projection system or I have to keep them in their original projection and transform my input data. A uniform coordinate system has advantages for me, but my only concern is data quality issues.